# Render Component with props based on an API call?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've been having some trouble lately trying to get a Component to work with props passed from an API call, as the Promise keeps breaking said Component. Is there a way to make the Component's execution wait until the Promise is fulfilled, or another way to treat this case?

In this specific case, `UserData`'s `userImage` property can't be set as the Promise is passed as undefined (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined`)

This is my main component

```
export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      playerName: "Catulus",
      gamemode: 1,
      playerData: null,
      playerBest: null
    }
    this.fetchAPI = this.fetchAPI.bind(this)
    this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this)
  }

  fetchAPI(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      this.fetchUser().then(result => {
        this.setState({
          playerData: <UserData info={this.state.playerData}/>,
        })
      })
  }

  fetchUser() {
    const userUrl = apiLink + userData + apiKey + "&u=" + this.state.playerName + "&m=" + this.state.gamemode + "&type=string"
    return axios.get(userUrl)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Subtitle">
          <form onSubmit={this.fetchAPI} style={{position: "relative", width: "100%"}}>
            <span style={{margin: "auto auto auto 0"}}>Search by player</span>
              <span className="fas fa-search"></span>
              <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" defaultValue={this.state.playerName} />
              <select name="mode" defaultValue= "1">
                <option value="0">osu!</option>
                <option value="1">osu!taiko</option>
                <option value="2">osu!catch</option>
                <option value="3">osu!mania</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" value="Search" id="SubmitButton" />
            </form>
          </div>
          {this.state.playerData}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the `UserData` component

```
export default class UserData extends Component {
  render() {
    const {data} = this.props
    console.log(data)
    const userImage = imageLink + data["user_id"] + "?.jpeg"
    return (
      <div className="UserDisplay">
        <table style={{width: "100%"}}>
          <tr>
            <td id="userImage"><img src={userImage} alt="User Avatar"></img></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

All variables not shown here have been correctly defined. Any advice or guide towards the right direction will be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not doing anything  fetchUser() result? You don't store JSX in the state, it's a very bad practice, also non-working one. <UserData info={this.state.playerData}/> playerData is a component and playerData is always null..

Comment: <UserData info={this.state.playerData}/> you are passing info here in UserData props and accessing const {data } in your UserData.change it to const {info} = this.porps

Comment: let me know if you have any other errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store entire components in the state. Only store the information needed to render them. Also, you're not using the result of the fetch, and you're state is also kinda referencing itself (since it's a component which has the state as a prop).

You'll want to do something like this:

```
    this.setState({
      playerData: result.data    // store data from result object in state
    })
```

and then render the component when the data is there:

```
{
    this.state.playerData === null ?
    "Loading player data..." :
    <UserData info={this.state.playerData} />
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't catch the autoreference. I just tried your fix, but the props for UserData are still getting sent when playerData is undefined. Is there a way to check if a Promise still hasn't been fulfilled?

Comment: The `UserData` won't render until the `playerData` has been set, that's what that ternary does. So if it's null, it should render that string instead. If you mean specifically the value "undefined", well then you can just do a basic falsy check instead `this.state.playerData ? ...`.

Comment: @ArmoredReaper there are ways to check Promise statuses, but you don't want to do it that way. You want to base the rendering off the presence of the data.

Comment: Finally got it working, thank you very much for the answer, really helped me understand how to handle Promises.